# Setting a custom cookie in the Redirectrule in apache

Tags: apache, redirect, cookies, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to set a custom cookie in the redirect rule of the apache, below is my existing redirect rule in Apache config file which redirects to 'blog.example.com'

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(blog)$
RewriteRule ^ http://blog.example.com/ [L,R=301]
```

I would like to send a custom cookie name/value to the 'blog.example.com' when the above rule is executed and for this I have tried as below

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(blog)$
RewriteRule ^ http://blog.example.com/ [CO=testsession:yes:.blog.example.com]
```

However this is not working, appreciate if someone help to add this. Thanks in advance

Comment: From which domain/hostname are you redirecting from.

Comment: It's from www.example.com - the above redirect rule work like this: www.example.com/blog -> blog.example.com and with this redirect only I'm trying to add a custom cookie

Answer (score 0):

> It's from `www.example.com` - the above redirect rule work like this: `www.example.com/blog` -> `blog.example.com` and with this redirect only I'm trying to add a custom cookie

That's the problem. You can't set a cookie on a different hostname - *browser* security prevents this. In other words, you can't set a cookie on `blog.example.com` when at `www.example.com`, which is what you are trying to do here. (However, if you were at `example.com` then you could set a cookie that is accessible from `blog.example.com`.)

The redirect *response* on which you are trying to set the cookie (on `blog.example.com`) goes back to `www.example.com`, only then does the browser issue a second request to `blog.example.com` (the target of the redirect).

In order to set the cookie on `blog.example.com` you need to set the cookie *after* the redirect has completed - when the user is already at `blog.example.com`.

Comment: Thanks @MrWhite - by the way blog.example.com is not hosted in the same server :(